# Как добавить в код модуля сортировку по ключевым словам

Tags: php, javascript, joomla

Здравствуйте! Имеется модуль для джумлы, но в нем нет сортировки по ключевым словам, хотела добавить самостоятельно (хотелось бы, чтобы выводились похожие статьи по ключевым словам, а если совпадений нет, то в искались бы совпадения по названию/тексту) но ничего не выходит. Не знаю точно, какой файл отвечает за сортировку, думаю, этот

```
<?php
/**
 * @package Related News
 * @version 2.5
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPL
 * @copyright (c) 2012 YouTech Company. All Rights Reserved.
 * @author YouTech Company http://www.smartaddons.com
 *
 */
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$com_path = JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_content/';
require_once $com_path.'router.php';
require_once $com_path.'helpers/route.php';
JModelLegacy::addIncludePath($com_path . '/models', 'ContentModel');

include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/helper_base.php';

class RelatedNews extends BaseHelper{

    public static function getList(&$_params)
    {
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        // Get an instance of the generic articles model
        $articles = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Articles', 'ContentModel', array('ignore_request' => true));
        // Set application parameters in model

        $articles->setState(
                'list.select',
                'a.id, a.title, a.alias, a.introtext, a.fulltext, ' .
                'a.checked_out, a.checked_out_time, ' .
                'a.catid, a.created, a.created_by, a.created_by_alias, ' .
                // use created if modified is 0
                'CASE WHEN a.modified = ' . $db->q($db->getNullDate()) . ' THEN a.created ELSE a.modified END as modified, ' .
                'a.modified_by, uam.name as modified_by_name,' .
                // use created if publish_up is 0
                'CASE WHEN a.publish_up = ' . $db->q($db->getNullDate()) . ' THEN a.created ELSE a.publish_up END as publish_up,' .
                'a.publish_down, a.images, a.urls, a.attribs, a.metadata, a.metakey, a.metadesc, a.access, ' .
                'a.hits, a.xreference, a.featured'
        );

        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $appParams = $app->getParams();

        $articles->setState('params', $appParams);
        // Set the filters based on the module params
        $articles->setState('list.start', 0);
        $articles->setState('list.limit', (int) $_params->get('count', 0)+1);
        $articles->setState('filter.published', 1);

        // Access filter
        $access = !JComponentHelper::getParams('com_content')->get('show_noauth');
        $authorised = JAccess::getAuthorisedViewLevels(JFactory::getUser()->get('id'));
        $articles->setState('filter.access', $access);

        // Category filter
        $catids = $_params->get('depends');
        if ($catids != null) {
            if ($_params->get('show_child_category_articles', 0) && (int) $_params->get('levels', 0) > 0) {
                // Get an instance of the generic categories model
                $categories = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Categories', 'ContentModel', array('ignore_request' => true));
                $categories->setState('params', $appParams);
                $levels = $_params->get('levels', 1) ? $_params->get('levels', 1) : 9999;
                $categories->setState('filter.get_children', $levels);
                $categories->setState('filter.published', 1);
                $categories->setState('filter.access', $access);
                $additional_catids = array();

                foreach($catids as $catid)
                {
                    $categories->setState('filter.parentId', $catid);
                    $recursive = true;
                    $items = $categories->getItems($recursive);

                    if ($items)
                    {
                        foreach($items as $category)
                        {
                            $condition = (($category->level - $categories->getParent()->level) <= $levels);
                            if ($condition) {
                                $additional_catids[] = $category->id;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }

                $catids = array_unique(array_merge($catids, $additional_catids));
            }
            $articles->setState('filter.category_id', $catids);

        // Ordering
        $articles->setState('list.ordering', $_params->get('article_ordering', 'a.ordering'));
        $articles->setState('list.direction', $_params->get('article_ordering_direction', 'ASC'));

//      // New Parameters
        $articles->setState('filter.featured', $_params->get('show_front', 'show'));

        // Filter by language
        $articles->setState('filter.language', $app->getLanguageFilter());

        $items = $articles->getItems();
        //var_dump($items); die("ancnc");
        //$show_introtext = $_params->get('show_introtext', 0);
        //$introtext_limit = $_params->get('introtext_limit', 100);
        $title_limit = $_params->get('item_title_max_characs', 20);

        // Find current Article ID if on an article page
        $option = $app->input->get('option');
        $view = $app->input->get('view');

        if ($option === 'com_content' && $view === 'article') {
            $active_article_id = $app->input->getInt('id');
        }
        else {
            $active_article_id = 0;
        }

        // Prepare data for display using display options
        foreach ($items as &$item)
        {
            $item->slug = $item->id.':'.$item->alias;
            $item->catslug = $item->catid ? $item->catid .':'.$item->category_alias : $item->catid;

            if ($access || in_array($item->access, $authorised))
            {
                // We know that user has the privilege to view the article
                $item->link = JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($item->slug, $item->catslug));
            }
            else
            {
                $app  = JFactory::getApplication();
                $menu = $app->getMenu();
                $menuitems = $menu->getItems('link', 'index.php?option=com_users&view=login');
                if (isset($menuitems[0]))
                {
                    $Itemid = $menuitems[0]->id;
                }
                elseif ($app->input->getInt('Itemid') > 0)
                {
                    // Use Itemid from requesting page only if there is no existing menu
                    $Itemid = $app->input->getInt('Itemid');
                }
                $item->link = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=login&Itemid='.$Itemid);
            }

            // Used for styling the active article
            $item->active = $item->id == $active_article_id ? 'active' : '';
            $item->title = BaseHelper::truncate($item->title, $title_limit);
            //if ($show_introtext) {
//              $item->introtext = JHtml::_('content.prepare', $item->introtext, '', 'plg_content_relatednews.content');
//              self::getImages($item, $_params);
//              $item->introtext = self::_cleanIntrotext($item->introtext);
            //} else {
                $item->introtext = JHtml::_('content.prepare', $item->introtext, '', 'plg_content_relatednews.content');
                BaseHelper::getArticleImages($item, $_params);
            //}
            //$item->displayIntrotext = $show_introtext ? self::truncate($item->introtext, $introtext_limit) : '';
            //$item->displayReadmore = $item->alternative_readmore;
        }
        return $items;
        }
    }

    public static function groupBy($list, $fieldName, $article_grouping_direction, $fieldNameToKeep = null)
    {
        $grouped = array();

        if (!is_array($list)) {
            if ($list == '') {
                return $grouped;
            }

            $list = array($list);
        }

        foreach($list as $key => $item)
        {
            if (!isset($grouped[$item->$fieldName])) {
                $grouped[$item->$fieldName] = array();
            }

            if (is_null($fieldNameToKeep)) {
                $grouped[$item->$fieldName][$key] = $item;
            }
            else {
                $grouped[$item->$fieldName][$key] = $item->$fieldNameToKeep;
            }

            unset($list[$key]);
        }

        $article_grouping_direction($grouped);

        return $grouped;
    }

    public static function groupByDate($list, $type = 'year', $article_grouping_direction, $month_year_format = 'F Y')
    {
        $grouped = array();

        if (!is_array($list)) {
            if ($list == '') {
                return $grouped;
            }

            $list = array($list);
        }

        foreach($list as $key => $item)
        {
            switch($type)
            {
                case 'month_year':
                    $month_year = JString::substr($item->created, 0, 7);

                    if (!isset($grouped[$month_year])) {
                        $grouped[$month_year] = array();
                    }

                    $grouped[$month_year][$key] = $item;
                    break;

                case 'year':
                default:
                    $year = JString::substr($item->created, 0, 4);

                    if (!isset($grouped[$year])) {
                        $grouped[$year] = array();
                    }

                    $grouped[$year][$key] = $item;
                    break;
            }

            unset($list[$key]);
        }

        $article_grouping_direction($grouped);

        if ($type === 'month_year') {
            foreach($grouped as $group => $items)
            {
                $date = new JDate($group);
                $formatted_group = $date->format($month_year_format);
                $grouped[$formatted_group] = $items;
                unset($grouped[$group]);
            }
        }

        return $grouped;
    }


}
```

В xml документ добавила, теперь опция сортировки по ключам есть в админпанели

```
<field name="article_ordering" type="list" default="a.title"
    label="Article Field to Order By"
    description="Select which field you would like Articles to be ordered by. Featured Ordering should only be used when Filtering Option for Featured Articles is set to 'Only'.">

    <option value="a.metakey">Article Kewords Order</option>
    <option value="a.ordering">Article Manager Order</option>
    <option value="fp.ordering">Featured Articles Order</option>
    <option value="a.hits">Hits</option>
    <option value="a.title">Title</option>
    <option value="a.id">ID</option>
    <option value="a.alias">Alias</option>
    <option value="a.created">Created Date</option>
    <option value="modified">Modified Date</option>
    <option value="publish_up">Start Publishing Date</option>
    <option value="a.publish_down">Finish Publishing Date</option>
</field>
```

Надеюсь на помощь, весь интернет перерыла в поисках подходящего модуля, но не нашла, поэтому хотелось бы этот "допилить", тем более, что стили уже все под себя переделала.
Может быть еще будет нужен вот этот файл

```
<?php
/**
 * @package Related News
 * @version 2.5
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPL
 * @copyright (c) 2012 YouTech Company. All Rights Reserved.
 * @author YouTech Company http://www.smartaddons.com
 *
 */
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
require_once JPATH_SITE.'/libraries/joomla/filesystem/folder.php';
JLoader::register('ImageHelper', dirname(__FILE__).'/helper_image.php');

if (!class_exists('BaseHelper')){
    abstract class BaseHelper{

        /**
         *
         * @param string $introtext
         * @return string
         */
        public function _cleanText($text){
            $text = str_replace('<p>', ' ', $text);
            $text = str_replace('</p>', ' ', $text);
            $text = strip_tags($text, '<a><em><strong>');
            $text = trim($text);
            return $text;
        }

        /**
         * Parse and build target attribute for links.
         * @param string $value (_self, _blank, _windowopen, _modal)
         */
        public static function parseTarget($value='_self'){
            $target = '';
            switch($value){
                default:
                case '0':
                case '_self':
                    break;
                case '1':
                case '_blank':
                    $target = "target=\"_blank\"";
                    break;
                case '2':
                case '_windowopen':
                    $target = "onclick=\"window.open(this.href,'targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,false');return false;\"";
                    break;
                case '3':
                case '_modal':
                    $target = "";
                    break;
            }
            return $target;
        }

        /**
         * Truncate string by $length
         * @param string $string
         * @param int $length
         * @param string $etc
         * @return string
         */
        public static function truncate($string, $length, $etc='...'){
            return defined('MB_OVERLOAD_STRING')
            ? self::_mb_truncate($string, $length, $etc)
            : self::_truncate($string, $length, $etc);
        }

        /**
         * Truncate string if it's size over $length
         * @param string $string
         * @param int $length
         * @param string $etc
         * @return string
         */
        private static function _truncate($string, $length, $etc='...'){
            if ($length>0 && $length<strlen($string)){
                $buffer = '';
                $buffer_length = 0;
                $parts = preg_split('/(<[^>]*>)/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
                $self_closing_tag = split(',', 'area,base,basefont,br,col,frame,hr,img,input,isindex,link,meta,param,embed');
                $open = array();

                foreach($parts as $i => $s){
                    if( false===strpos($s, '<') ){
                        $s_length = strlen($s);
                        if ($buffer_length + $s_length < $length){
                            $buffer .= $s;
                            $buffer_length += $s_length;
                        } else if ($buffer_length + $s_length == $length) {
                            if ( !empty($etc) ){
                                $buffer .= ($s[$s_length - 1]==' ') ? $etc : " $etc";
                            }
                            break;
                        } else {
                            $words = preg_split('/([^\s]*)/', $s, - 1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
                            $space_end = false;
                            foreach ($words as $w){
                                if ($w_length = strlen($w)){
                                    if ($buffer_length + $w_length < $length){
                                        $buffer .= $w;
                                        $buffer_length += $w_length;
                                        $space_end = (trim($w) == '');
                                    } else {
                                        if ( !empty($etc) ){
                                            $more = $space_end ? $etc : " $etc";
                                            $buffer .= $more;
                                            $buffer_length += strlen($more);
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        preg_match('/^<([\/]?\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s?[^>]*>$/', $s, $m);
                        //$tagclose = isset($m[1]) && trim($m[1])=='/';
                        if (empty($m[1]) && isset($m[2]) && !in_array($m[2], $self_closing_tag)){
                            array_push($open, $m[2]);
                        } else if (trim($m[1])=='/') {
                            $tag = array_pop($open);
                            if ($tag != $m[2]){
                                // uncomment to to check invalid html string.
                                // die('invalid close tag: '. $s);
                            }
                        }
                        $buffer .= $s;
                    }
                }
                // close tag openned.
                while(count($open)>0){
                    $tag = array_pop($open);
                    $buffer .= "</$tag>";
                }
                return $buffer;
            }
            return $string;
        }

        /**
         * Truncate mutibyte string if it's size over $length
         * @param string $string
         * @param int $length
         * @param string $etc
         * @return string
         */
        private static function _mb_truncate($string, $length, $etc='...'){
            $encoding = mb_detect_encoding($string);
            if ($length>0 && $length<mb_strlen($string, $encoding)){
                $buffer = '';
                $buffer_length = 0;
                $parts = preg_split('/(<[^>]*>)/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
                $self_closing_tag = explode(',', 'area,base,basefont,br,col,frame,hr,img,input,isindex,link,meta,param,embed');
                $open = array();

                foreach($parts as $i => $s){
                    if (false === mb_strpos($s, '<')){
                        $s_length = mb_strlen($s, $encoding);
                        if ($buffer_length + $s_length < $length){
                            $buffer .= $s;
                            $buffer_length += $s_length;
                        } else if ($buffer_length + $s_length == $length) {
                            if ( !empty($etc) ){
                                $buffer .= ($s[$s_length - 1]==' ') ? $etc : " $etc";
                            }
                            break;
                        } else {
                            $words = preg_split('/([^\s]*)/', $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
                            $space_end = false;
                            foreach ($words as $w){
                                if ($w_length = mb_strlen($w, $encoding)){
                                    if ($buffer_length + $w_length < $length){
                                        $buffer .= $w;
                                        $buffer_length += $w_length;
                                        $space_end = (trim($w) == '');
                                    } else {
                                        if ( !empty($etc) ){
                                            $more = $space_end ? $etc : " $etc";
                                            $buffer .= $more;
                                            $buffer_length += mb_strlen($more);
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        preg_match('/^<([\/]?\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s?[^>]*>$/', $s, $m);
                        //$tagclose = isset($m[1]) && trim($m[1])=='/';
                        if (empty($m[1]) && isset($m[2]) && !in_array($m[2], $self_closing_tag)){
                            array_push($open, $m[2]);
                        } else if (trim($m[1])=='/') {
                            $tag = array_pop($open);
                            if ($tag != $m[2]){
                                // uncomment to to check invalid html string.
                                // die('invalid close tag: '. $s);
                            }
                        }
                        $buffer .= $s;
                    }
                }
                // close tag openned.
                while(count($open)>0){
                    $tag = array_pop($open);
                    $buffer .= "</$tag>";
                }
                return $buffer;
            }
            return $string;
        }


        public static $image_article_cache = array();
        public static function getArticleImage($item, $_params, $ctype='article'){
            $images = &self::getArticleImages($item, $_params, $ctype);
            return is_array($images) && count($images) ? $images[0] : null;
        }

        public static function getArticleImages($item, $_params, $ctype='article'){
            $hash = md5( serialize(array($_params, $ctype)) );
            if ( !isset(self::$image_article_cache[$hash][$item->id]) ){
                $defaults = array(
                        'external'  => 1,
                        'image_intro'       => 1,
                        'inline_introtext'  => 1,
                        'image_fulltext'    => 1,
                        'inline_fulltext'   => 1
                );
                $images_path = array();
                $priority = preg_split('/[\s|,|;]/', $_params->get('imgcfg_order', 'external, imagE_intro,inline_introtext,image_fulltext,inline_fulltext'), -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
                if ( count($priority) > 0 ){
                    $priority = array_map('strtolower', $priority);
                    $mark = array();

                    for($i=0; $i<count($priority); $i++){
                        $type = $priority[$i];
                        if ( array_key_exists($type, $defaults) )
                            unset($defaults[ $type ]);
                        if ( $_params->get('imgcfg_from_'.$type, 1) )
                            $mark[ $type ] = 1;
                    }
                }
                foreach($defaults as $type => $val){
                    if ( $_params->get('imgcfg_from_'.$type, 1) )
                        $mark[ $type ] = 1;
                }
                if ( count($mark) > 0 ){
                    // prepare data.
                    $images_data = null;
                    if (array_key_exists('image_intro', $mark) || array_key_exists('image_fulltext', $mark)){
                        $images_data = json_decode($item->images, true);
                    }

                    foreach($mark as $type => $true){
                        switch ($type){
                            case 'image_intro':
                            case 'image_fulltext':
                                if ( isset($images_data) && isset($images_data[$type]) && !empty($images_data[$type])){
                                    $image = array(
                                            'src' => $images_data[$type]
                                    );
                                    if (array_key_exists($type.'_alt', $images_data)){
                                        $image['alt'] = $images_data[$type.'_alt'];
                                    }
                                    if (array_key_exists($type.'_caption', $images_data)){
                                        /* $image['class'] = 'caption'; */
                                        $image['title'] = $images_data[$type.'_caption'];
                                    }
                                    array_push($images_path, $image);
                                }
                                break;
                            case 'inline_introtext':
                                $text = $item->introtext;
                            case 'inline_fulltext':
                                if ($type == 'inline_fulltext'){
                                    $text = $item->fulltext;
                                }
                                $inline_images = self::getInlineImages($text);
                                for ($i=0; $i<count($inline_images); $i++){
                                    array_push($images_path, $inline_images[$i]);
                                }
                                break;

                            case 'external':
                                $exf = $_params->get('imgcfg_external_url', '/images');
                                preg_match_all('/{([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)}/', $exf, $m);
                                if ( count($m)==2 && count($m[0])>0 ){
                                    $compat = 1;
                                    foreach ($m[1] as $property){
                                        !property_exists($item, $property) && ($compat=0);
                                    }
                                    if ($compat){
                                        $replace = array();
                                        foreach ($m[1] as $property){
                                            $replace[] = is_null($item->$property) ? '' : $item->$property;
                                        }
                                        $exf = str_replace($m[0], $replace, $exf);
                                    }
                                }
                                $files = self::getExternalImages($exf);
                                for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++){
                                    array_push($images_path, array('src'=>$files[$i]));
                                }
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if ( count($images_path) == 0 && $_params->get('imgcfg_placeholder', 1)==1){
                    $images_path[] = array('src'=> $_params->get('imgcfg_placeholder_path', null), 'class'=>'placeholder');
                }

                self::$image_article_cache[$hash][$item->id] = $images_path;
            }
            return self::$image_article_cache[$hash][$item->id];
        }

        public static $image_category_cache = array();
        public static function getCategoryImage($item, $_params, $ctype='category'){
            $images = &self::getCategoryImages($item, $_params, $ctype);
            return is_array($images) && count($images) ? $images[0] : null;
        }

        public static function getCategoryImages($item, $_params, $ctype='category'){
            $hash = md5( serialize(array($_params, $ctype)) );
            if ( !isset(self::$image_category_cache[$hash][$item->id]) ){
                $defaults = array(
                        'external'      => 1,
                        'params'        => 1,
                        'description'   => 1
                );
                $images_path = array();
                $priority = preg_split('/[\s|,|;]/', $_params->get('imgcfg_order', 'external, params, description'), -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
                if ( count($priority) > 0 ){
                    $priority = array_map('strtolower', $priority);
                    $mark = array();

                    for($i=0; $i<count($priority); $i++){
                        $type = $priority[$i];
                        if ( array_key_exists($type, $defaults) )
                            unset($defaults[ $type ]);
                        if ( $_params->get('imgcfg_from_'.$type, 1) )
                            $mark[ $type ] = 1;
                    }
                }
                foreach($defaults as $type => $val){
                    if ( $_params->get('imgcfg_from_'.$type, 1) )
                        $mark[ $type ] = 1;
                }
                if ( count($mark) > 0 ){
                    $cparams = null;
                    if (array_key_exists('params', $mark)){
                        $cparams = new JRegistry;
                        $cparams->loadString($item->params);
                    }

                    foreach($mark as $type => $true){
                        switch ($type){
                            case 'params':
                                if ( $cparams instanceof JRegistry && $cparams->get('image') ){
                                    $image = array(
                                            'src' => $cparams->get('image')
                                    );
                                    array_push($images_path, $image);
                                }
                                break;
                            case 'description':
                                $inline_images = self::getInlineImages($item->description);
                                for ($i=0; $i<count($inline_images); $i++){
                                    array_push($images_path, $inline_images[$i]);
                                }
                                break;

                            case 'external':
                                $exf = $_params->get('imgcfg_external_url', '/images');
                                preg_match_all('/{([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)}/', $exf, $m);
                                if ( count($m)==2 && count($m[0])>0 ){
                                    $compat = 1;
                                    foreach ($m[1] as $property){
                                        !property_exists($item, $property) && ($compat=0);
                                    }
                                    if ($compat){
                                        $replace = array();
                                        foreach ($m[1] as $property){
                                            $replace[] = is_null($item->$property) ? '' : $item->$property;
                                        }
                                        $exf = str_replace($m[0], $replace, $exf);
                                    }
                                }
                                $files = self::getExternalImages($exf);
                                for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++){
                                    array_push($images_path, array('src'=>$files[$i]));
                                }
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if ( count($images_path) == 0 && $_params->get('imgcfg_placeholder', 1)==1){
                    $images_path[] = array('src'=> $_params->get('imgcfg_placeholder_path', null), 'class'=>'placeholder');
                }

                self::$image_category_cache[$hash][$item->id] = $images_path;
            }
            return self::$image_category_cache[$hash][$item->id];
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param string $text
         * @return string:
         */
        public static function getInlineImages($text){
            $images = array();
            $searchTags = array(
                    'img'   => '/<img[^>]+>/i',
                    'input' => '/<input[^>]+type\s?=\s?"image"[^>]+>/i'
            );
            foreach ($searchTags as $tag => $regex){
                preg_match_all($regex, $text, $m);
                if ( is_array($m) && isset($m[0]) && count($m[0])){
                    foreach ($m[0] as $htmltag){
                        $tmp = JUtility::parseAttributes($htmltag);
                        if ( isset($tmp['src']) ){
                            if ($tag == 'input'){
                                array_push( $images, array('src' => $tmp['src']) );
                            } else {
                                array_push( $images, $tmp );
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return $images;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param string $path
         * @return multitype:multitype:unknown  |Ambigous <multitype:, boolean, multitype:unknown multitype:unknown  >
         */
        public static function getExternalImages($path){
            $files = array();
            $ps = JString::parse_url($path);
            if ( array_key_exists('path', $ps) && !empty($ps['path']) ){
                $isHttp = isset($ps['scheme']) && in_array($ps['scheme'], array('http', 'https'));
                if (!$isHttp || JURI::isInternal($path)){
                    // image on server
                    $path = $ps['path'];
                } else {
                    $files[] = array( 'src' => $path );
                    return $files;
                }
            }

            if (is_file($path)){
                $files[] = $path;
            } else if (is_dir($path)){
                $files = JFolder::files($path, '.jpg|.png|.gif', false, true);
            } else {
                $ext = substr($path, -4);
                $search = substr($path, 0, -4);
                $lext = strtolower($ext);
                if ( is_dir($search) && in_array($lext, array('.jpg', '.png', '.gif')) ){
                    $files = JFolder::files($search, $ext, false, true);
                }
            }
            return $files;
        }

        public static function imageTag($image, $options=array()){
            return ImageHelper::init($image, $options)->tag();
        }

        public static function getImageHelper($image, $options=array()){
            return ImageHelper::init($image, $options);
        }

    }
}
```

Мне хотя бы нужно узнать, где находится код.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Вам лучше обратиться к профессионалам. Здесь нужна доработка системной модели Joomla, а это потребует значительных навыков.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, очень простое решение, можно сделать запрос на выборку по полям с ключевыми словами, извлечь все (запомнить id записей), после уже делать запрос по поиску в текстовых полях (если это будет необходимо по твоему условия, и где id записей != тем что уже запомнили) и выдать результат отсортировав тебе его в нужном порядке. Нужный код находится в модели (см. где ты обращаешься к бд)